# Declaring a 2-D array in verilog gives me a error illegal redeclaration of the variable

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, verilog, xilinx-ise

I am trying to initialize a 2d array in verilog as shown in the below code snippet.

```
parameter N=4;
 reg [N-1:0] number_c[2**N-1:0];
 reg [N-1:0] result_c;
```

after compiling I am getting the following error

> ERROR:HDLCompilers:27 - "Combinational_output.v" line 24 Illegal redeclaration of 'number_c'
>   ERROR:HDLCompilers:27 - "Combinational_output.v" line 25 Illegal redeclaration of 'result_c'

and my module looks like this

```
module Combinational_outputss(output number_c,output result_c
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing ANSI and non-ANSI port styles.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 23.2.3 *Parameterized modules*.  This uses ANSI style:

```
module Combinational_outputss #(parameter N=4)
(
    output reg [N-1:0] number_c[2**N-1:0],
    output reg [N-1:0] result_c
);
```